# Trim a string based on its byte length

Tags: java, string

I want to trim the string based on byte length (not character length), then how to achieve this?

Example: 
`String country = "日本日本日";`

One Japanese character will be 3 bytes. Above string length is 5, byte length is 15. If I give 3, only 1st character should be printed. If I give 5, only 1st character should come, because 2 characters size is 6 bytes. If I give 6, first 2 characters should be printed.

Edit: Byte size varies depends on the String. It may Japanese (or) Japanese with numerals (or) some other language.

Comment: "One Japanese character will be 3 bytes." That depends entirely on the encoding. Why do you want to do something like this?

Comment: I want to print the text in some file based on the byte length. The file accepts only fixed length. If allowed length is 10, 10 English characters are accepted as the byte length is 10. But for 10 japanese characters, the byte length is 30, so its failing to write.

Comment: What encoding does the file use?

Comment: You can directly do it by (as @Kayaman mentioned, it depends on the encoding. But if you are always sure then can be done by this dirty approach:) `country.subString(0, yourNumber/3);`.

Comment: This won't work when string contain English (or) mixed of japanese and numbers, or some other language (which is different byte size). I will edit the question.

Comment: This code fixed my issue. [https://gist.github.com/lpar/1031951] Thanks for all your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Divide your required byte with 3 and fetch those characters. For ex.

```
int requiredBytes = 5;
int requiredLength = 5 / 3;
System.out.println(country.subString(0,requiredLength));
```